# Has my iteration stopped responding? And is there any way I can make it fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have a list of over 100 million emails, so I decided to write a program to check which out of them are real ones. So I took 150K emails and started iterating. I added print("#") to keep a check if the iteration is going on or not but after about 100 or 200 emails it gets stuck there. Now has my iteration stopped or the vs code terminal is allowing only this much of lines in its terminal? Also, is there any way to make my code faster? It's taking too long.

P.S I am new to coding and stackoverflow , please ignore if I made any mistake while uploading this question.

```
import re
import dns.resolver
import socket
import smtplib
import pandas as pd
import json

df=[]
data=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\win10\Downloads\USA Emails.xlsx")
data=data.iloc[:,0].tolist()

for n in data:
    addressToVerify =str(n)
    match = re.match('^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$', addressToVerify)
    res = addressToVerify[addressToVerify.index('@') + 1 : ]
   
    if match == None:
        result_1={n:'Bad Syntax'}
        df.append(result_1)
        print("#")
        continue
    try:

        records = dns.resolver.query(res,'MX')


        #print(records)
        mxRecord = records[0].exchange
        mxRecord = str(mxRecord)

        



        # Get local server hostname
        host = socket.gethostname()

        # SMTP lib setup (use debug level for full output)
        server = smtplib.SMTP()
        server.set_debuglevel(0)

        # SMTP Conversation
        server.connect(mxRecord)
        server.helo(host)
        server.mail('me@domain.com')
        code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
        server.quit()

    except:
        result_2={n:'Server Unreachable'}
        df.append(result_2)
        print("##")
        continue

    # Assume 250 as Success
    if code == 250:
        result_3={n:"Success"}
        df.append(result_3)
        print("########")
    else:
        result_4={n:"Bad"}
        df.append(result_4)
        print("#####")

with open('dataaa','w') as fout:
    json.dump(df,fout)
```

This is the output

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\win10\Desktop> & C:/Users/win10/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/win10/Desktop/script.py
##
##
#
##
##
##
#
########
##
##
##
########
##
##
##
#####
##
#
#####
########
#####
##
#####
##
#
##
##
##
##
#
##
##
##
########
##
##
##
##
##
##
########
#####
##
#####
##
#
#####
##
##
##
##
#####
##
##
##
#####
#####
########
##
#####
##
##
##
##
##
########
########
#####
##
########
#
##
########
##
#####
##
##
##
##
##
##
##
#
#
##
##
#####
#
##
##
##
##
########
##
##
##
##
#####
########
##
#####
##
##
##
##
#
##
#####
#####
##
##
#
##
##
#
##
##
##
##
########
#####
##
##
#
##
#
##
########
#####
##
#####
##
#
#
##
##
##
########
##
#####
##
########
##
##
##
##
##
##
#####
##
########
##
##
#
##
##
##
########
##
##
########
##
##
#####
##
##
##
#####
########
##
##
########
##
#
#####
##
##
#####
########
#####
#####
##
########
#####
##
#
#####
##
##
##
##
########
##
##
##
##
##
##
##
##
##
##
##
#
##
##
##
##
#####
##
##
##
#####
########
##
#####
#####
########
##
##
##
########
##
##
##
########
#####
##
#####
#####
##
#####
#
########
#####
########
#####
#####
##
##
##
##
##
##
##
########
##
##
##
##
##
##
#####
##
#####
#####
##
##
########
##
##
##
##
##
##
#
##
##
##
#
########
##
##
##
#####
##
#####
##
#####
##
##
#####
#####
##
#####
##
##
#####
##
########
##
#
##
##
##
########
##
##
##
##
##
#####
########
##
##
#
#
##
##
#
#
##
##
##
########
##
########
##
#
#
##
#####
##
##
##
##
##
#####
##
##
##
##
##
##
##
##
########
##
##
##
#####
#####
##
##
##
#####
##
########
########
########
##
##
#####
########
##
##
##
########
##
##
##
##
########
##
##
##
##
##
#####
##
##
##
##
#####
########
##
##
##
#####
#####
#####
```

This is where it stops

Comment: You are trying to resolve 150000 DNS queries in rapid succession. You're probably getting blocked.

Comment: What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Don't do that? Download a hosts file or something; at the very least, cache your queries.

Comment: But I'd expect your OS to be caching, so it's probably okay. You don't look like you're printing anything in the `try` block, so the absence of printing might not be an issue.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 So should I leave my system as it is in the hope that when I wake up it will be all done?

Comment: @JatinDeswal You could use a network traffic monitor like Wireshark (or a system resource monitor, like the SysInternals tools) to check whether it's still making the SMTP connections.

Comment: Wait, is this your _actual_ code? `me@domain.com` included? That's not a real email address.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I found this code on stackoverflow itself, i made some changes according to my needs and that's all. Please , if you have any suggestions, I would be overwhelmed to hear. Thankyou